Huge increase in Clock Cycles When Calling TensorFlow Lite Micro (TFLM) Invoke Function from C Program
I'm using TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers (TFLM) in a C project, and I'm trying to call the Invoke function to perform inference. To achieve this, I wrote a function in C++ and compiled it as part of my C project. Here is the function I created:
extern "C"  int tflm_inference_int8(int8_t* numElementsInputTensors, int8_t** inputTensors, const int16_t* inputTensorShapes,
                                    int8_t* numElementsOutputTensors, int8_t** outputTensors, const int16_t* outputTensorShapes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *numElementsInputTensors; i++) {
        memcpy(g_interpreter->input(i)->data.int8, inputTensors[i], inputTensorShapes[i] * sizeof(int8_t));
    }

    if (kTfLiteOk != g_interpreter->Invoke()) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < *numElementsOutputTensors; i++) {
        memcpy(outputTensors[i], g_interpreter->output(i)->data.int8, outputTensorShapes[i] * sizeof(int8_t));
    }
    return 0;
}

The function is designed to:
Copy input data into the TFLM interpreter's input tensors.
Call the Invoke method of the global TFLM interpreter (g_interpreter).
Copy the output data from the interpreter's output tensors back into the provided buffers.
The function compiles and runs without any errors, but I’m encountering a significant increase in the number of clock cycles consumed by this function when it's being executed on hardware in my C project. The increase is far beyond what I measure in simulation in my c++.

I’ve confirmed that the input and output data copying using memcpy is working correctly.

I’ve profiled the code and identified that most of the additional clock cycles are consumed during the g_interpreter->Invoke() call.

I've tried simplifying the input data to reduce tensor size, but the increase in clock cycles remains disproportionate.


What could be causing this significant increase in clock cycles when invoking the TensorFlow Lite Micro Invoke function? Are there any known inefficiencies or considerations when integrating TFLM with C projects that could explain this behavior?
